# Java string sorting

Tags: java, string, class

This is no homework.Its an exercise I came across in a book.
Build a class named Name which represents the name of a person.The class should have fields that represent first name ,last name ,and fathersname.
The class should have these methods :

```
public Name (String fn,String f_n,String ln)
    /* initializes the fields of an object with the values fn,f_n and m.
       fn means first name
       ln means last name
       f_n means fathersname btw. */

public String getNormalOrder(); //returns the name of the person in the normal order : first name,fathers name,last name.

public String getReverseOrder(); //returns the name of the person in the reverse order : last name,fathers name,first name.

public boolean compare (String fn,String f_n,String ln); // Returns true if the first name is the same with fn,fathers name is the same with f_n, last name with ln.If the opposite happens it returns false.
```

Build a program named TestName which tests the methods of the class Firstname.

**My solution**

```
public class Name {
    String fn;
    String f_n;
    String ln;

    public Name(String initialfn, String initialf_n, String initialln) {
        fn = initialfn;
        f_n = initialf_n;
        ln = initialln;
    }

    public String getNormalOrder() {
        return fn + " " + f_n +
            " " + ln;
    }

    public String getReverseOrder() {
        return ln + ", " + f_n +
            " " + fn + " ";
    }
}
```

How about the third method which is comparing? Also how do I test the class?

Answer (score 1):

For a flexible solution:

```
public enum NameMember {
    FIRSTNAME, SECONDNAME, FATHERSNAME;
}
```

The `Name` class:

```
public class Name {
    private final String firstName;
    private final String secondName;
    private final String fathersName;

    public Name(String firstName, String secondName, String fathersName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.secondName = secondName;
        this.fathersName = fathersName;
    }

    public String getName(NameMember member1, NameMember member2, NameMember member3) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        return sb.append(getMember(member1)).append(" ")
                .append(getMember(member2)).append(" ")
                .append(getMember(member3)).toString();
    }

    public String getMember(NameMember member) {
        switch (member) {
            case FIRSTNAME:
                return firstName;
            case SECONDNAME:
                return secondName;
            case FATHERSNAME:
                return fathersName;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getName(NameMember.FIRSTNAME, NameMember.SECONDNAME, NameMember.FATHERSNAME);
    }
}
```

A `NameComparator` (flexible) class:

```
import java.util.Comparator;

public class NameComparator implements Comparator<Name> {

    private NameMember nameMember;

    public NameComparator(NameMember nameMember) {
        this.nameMember = nameMember;
    }

    @Override
    public int compare(Name name1, Name name2) {
        return name1.getMember(nameMember).compareTo(name2.getMember(nameMember));
    }
}
```

And the main class (test drive):

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    List<Name> names = new ArrayList<>();
    names.add(new Name("Alice", "Burda", "Christophe"));
    names.add(new Name("Ben", "Ashton", "Caine"));
    names.add(new Name("Chane", "Bagwell", "Alex"));
    names.add(new Name("Ann", "Clinton", "Brad"));

    System.out.println("NAMES ORDERED BY FIRST NAME:");
    Collections.sort(names, new NameComparator(NameMember.FIRSTNAME));
    printNames(names);

    System.out.println("\nNAMES ORDERED BY SECOND NAME:");
    Collections.sort(names, new NameComparator(NameMember.SECONDNAME));
    printNames(names);

    System.out.println("\nNAMES ORDERED BY FATHERSNAME:");
    Collections.sort(names, new NameComparator(NameMember.FATHERSNAME));
    printNames(names);
}

private static void printNames(Collection<Name> names) {
    names.stream().forEach(System.out::println);
}
```